# My app was not installing. Installation has failed while the process

Tags: java, android

Here is screenshot of error which I am facing

[image: Here is screenshot of error which I am facing]

When I am installing the app-debug.apk file of my project in android studio to my android device. It shows app not installed. but the same working good in emulators.

Comment: Are there any errors showing in the Android Studio console or logcat?

Comment: thank you for responding. no errors showing there. everything works good in android studio.

Comment: is that source file is the right one to install. imean, app-debug.apk?

Comment: How are you installing it? Via the Run button?

Comment: no i have copied that file to my phone and then i  installed.

Comment: Well, there's your problem. Either install via the run button in Android Studio, or use `adb install` from your PC.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the app already installed in android device then install the app again it will work .

Comment: app didn't installed at least one time. every time it is showing the same.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling the app first in the device and clearing the cache of device ?

Comment: yah, i have did it.. but the same happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:


1.  Go to Settings of your Android device.
2.  Open Apps or Application manager.
3.  Check for All Apps.
4.  Tap on menu icon.
5.  Click on ‘Reset App Preferences’.

Comment: Note that Markdown supports list items here, which are a bit more readable than home-made ones. Just put a blank line before the first item, and ensure that there is a space after each numbered item, including the dot: `1. `